# Java regex return after first matched pattern

Tags: java

I want to extract word after first 'from' in the following string-

> "anti-CD24 from Chemicon, and anti-CD48 from Santa"

Right now, I am using -

> "from\s+([^\s]+)"

But it is giving both results 'Chemicon' and 'Santa' instead of only 'Chemicon'.

Comment: Then just use the first result?

Comment: how to extract out the first result? I am using `if (m.find())` and it is giving both results instead of first one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `lookingAt` method on the Method object. It stops after it finds the first match.

Like the `matches` function and unlike the `find` function `lookingAt` has to match from the beginning, so we have to use the regex `".*?from\\s+(\\w+)"`, which says: match anything up until the first "from", then one or more whitespace chars, then the next "word". If you only want alphabetical chars to match your word after "from" then use `".*?from\\s+([a-zA-Z])"`.  The `".*?"` at the beginning means non-greedy matching.  If you just use `".*"` it will match the last "from", not the first one.

Here's code that I've tested:

```
  String s = "anti-CD24 from Chemicon, and anti-CD48 from Santa";
  Matcher m = Pattern.compile(".*?from\\s+(\\w+)").matcher(s);
  if (m.lookingAt()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
  }
```

Prints out:

```
Chemicon
```

Comment: thanx, it even worked with using `find`, after i used `.*?` instead of `.*`

Comment: Yes, good catch - that also works in this case.  Because we use non-greedy matching of any character that would make find work like lookingAt in this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could do something like this:

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("from\\s+([^\\s]+)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher("anti-CD24 from Chemicon, and anti-CD48 from Santa");
    if (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
    }
```

This would take just the first one. And maybe you could use this regular expression to avoid the comma for the first match (`Chemicon,`): `from\\s+([a-zA-Z]+)`

Comment: Gosh! Was gonna type the very same code after I just implemented it in my Eclipse.. +1 for being faster than me lol

Comment: thanx, but i am using like `anti-CD24.*from\\s+([^\\s]+)`, in which case it is actually matching the last one ie. 'Santa', but i want to extract 'Chemicon,'